# Getting play services and a simple login flow working on Android

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have been struggling to get an Android application to work with the Google APIs. My end goal is fairly simple: I to give the user the ability to login and authenticate with their Google account. To do this, I've looked at a wide variety of tutorials, the following being the most recent attempts.

[Quickstart Sample](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/samples/quickstart-android)

[Integrating Google Play Services on Android](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/integrating-google-play-services-on-android--cms-19828)

[Backend Authentication](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth)

[Authorizing with Google for REST APIs](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/http-auth)

[Getting people and profile information](https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/)

However, I've run into a swath of problems.

## Quickstart Sample

[Quickstart Sample](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/samples/quickstart-android)

In trying to run the google quickstart sample, I get the error

> Google Play services is not available. This application will close.

I believe that this is probably the root cause for the other errors I get.

## Integrating Google Play Services on Android

[Integrating Google Play Services on Android](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/integrating-google-play-services-on-android--cms-19828)

For instance, when I try to use Google+ services for a simple test in the app,

```
        Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(googleApiClient);
```

the variable `currentPerson` is null. In the documentation, it states:

> This method can return null if the required scopes weren't specified in the GoogleApiClient.Builder, or if there was a network error while connecting.

So I ensure that both scopes are available:

```
    GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(onConnectionListener)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(onConnectionListener)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.EMAIL))
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
            .build();
```

## Backend Authentication

[Backend Authentication](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth)

In attempting to follow the Backend Authentication guide, an exception is thrown at the following line in the suggested `GetTokenIdTask` class:

```
return GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context, account, scopes);
```

The exception message is singularly useless:

```
com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown
```

My assumption is that this has to do with my `SERVER_CLIENT_ID` variable, which I use (like the example) when specifying a scope string:

```
String scopes = "audience:server:client_id:" + SERVER_CLIENT_ID; // Not the app's client ID.
```

Because the guide doesn't ever state what `SERVER_CLIENT_ID` actually *is*, I just assumed it was the `Client Id` you get when you make `Web Application` credentials.

Because I think permissions might be relevant in this, here are the ones I have listed in my `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<permission
    android:name="xyz.tyde.restaurant.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" /> <!-- To retrieve the account name (email) as part of sign-in: -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" /> <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

I assumed that I would get a `Runtime Exception` if my permissions were inaccurate, but who knows.

## The Question(s)

Alright, so this all adds up to me being in a pickle.

Really I have a short series of related (hopefully) questions:

1. Is the check for play services on the quickstart sample app just outdated? Or is it behaving properly, and something else is going wrong? If so, what is the problem?
2. Is there another reason the `getCurrentPerson` call would return `null`? If so, what can I do to fix it? What things should I check for to make sure everything is set up for this call to work?
3. What should I set the `SERVER_CLIENT_ID` variable to? What should I check in my credentials to make sure it works? Is there a sandbox I can use to ensure this stuff is right?

Ok, so that is very specific to my situation. Really, though, what these questions boil down to is as follows:

4. Can I get a clear, simple explanation of the flow of using Google Play Services, what Google Play Services refers to, and what the use of the Google credentials and client ids are? Can I get a high-level overview of what I am doing with APIs, Scopes, and google packages?

Comment: did you try with device or emulator?

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira Both.

Comment: Is all errors still exists. including play services not available?

Comment: @haseeb Yes? Could you clarify the question a bit?

Comment: You'll have to clear that "Play Services not available" issue first. Add [this](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(android.content.Context)) check in your code.